# ArrayList - Im getting error 'E cannot be resolved to a type'

Tags: arraylist

While trying ArrayList, I'm getting an error 'E cannot be resolved to a type', I want to use different data types in a program, instead of declaring particular data type, I'm using 'E', which I guess accepts all type of data types. Please check the below code, I'm using Java 1.8 version.

```
public class ArrayListDemo1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<E> ar1=new ArrayList<E>(); //'E' displaying error(on mouse hovering its stating that 'E cannot be resolved to a type')

        ar1.add("Abc");
        ar1.add(123);
        ar1.add("Xyz");

        }
```

Comment: What is E there? You are trying with totally wrong syntax. Please read it first https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html

Comment: You have to replace the `E` with Class name. If you want to use int than it should be `ArrayList<Integer> ar1=new ArrayList<Integer>();`

Comment: If you want it to store string and integer than you can use like `ArrayList<Object> ar1=new ArrayList<Object>();`

Comment: Thanks, its working by using --> ArrayList<Object> ar1=new ArrayList<Object>();